# Idea of Mean Value Constraints

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mean-value-theorem

I'm working on the following problem laplace problem with neumann boundary condition. I was educated that such problem will have a unique solution if we apply the mean value constraint, namely, if $u$ is the solution and $\Omega$ is the domain, then we need to impose $\int_{\Omega} u ds = 0$ to the problem to ensure a solution.

My question is : How do mathematician come up with such idea? Are there any other way that serves as a replacement to dirichlet boundary condition other than mean value constraint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well in this case—the Neumann problem, not Dirichlet—someone noticed that adding a constant to any solution would give you another solution, so this is one way to fix that constant. After that it’s s matter of proving that that constraint implies uniqueness.

Comment: @Aruralreader I see, sounds interesting